# regex to get date yyyy-mm-dd from any string

Tags: php, regex, date, datetime

first of all excuse me for not being regex familiar that much.What I Would like is a regex that will extract a date like mysql date from any type of string.
Until now I was using this : `^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$`

However now I want to extract date patterns from other strings and datetime strings I tried altering the regex to `^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).` based on some online regex testers, but it fails. Also some times it gave me a result with a 3 digit day.

In other words sting starts with, `yyyy-mm-dd` and is followed up by spaces characters numbers or anything. How do I extract the date?

**UPDATE**

I'm testing regex with preg_match here: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm

so far the only thing that seems to work is

```
[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145133/preg-match-for-mysql-date-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match dates wherever they appear, remove the `$` and `^` anchors from your original regex.

To match dates at the start of any input remove the `$` at the end (leave the `^`).

You can also put the remaining pattern inside parentheses for convenience, so that the match is also captured as a whole.

Your suggested improvement has a spurious dot at the end which will match any character; that was the reason for returning matches with three-digit days.

Answer (score 8):

If your string has more than one date form value occurrence and you wanna capture all of them you should use `preg_match_all` function and if it's not `preg_match` is enough. Also using `^` and `$` means input string is should be just a date, so avoid it.

```
<?php
$input_string = "yes today is 2013-10-24";
if(preg_match("/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/", $input_string, $match))
{
    print_r($match);
}
else
    echo "not matched";
////////////////////////
/* Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-10-24
)
*/
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/LMPV0y)

Comment: no it will have only 1 date sorry for not being clear about this.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:
you can use `preg_match()` or `preg_match_all()`

```
   $dateArray = preg_match("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/", $str, $match);
```

Then use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($match[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `^` for `\b`.

```
\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is dot in the end of your regexp (it matches any character, except for line breaks)
Try removing it

```
^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])
```