# how to convert date format in a textarea php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cakephp

I want to change the date format in a text area,

```
<textarea tabindex="0"
class="input_lkl  "
name=""><?php echo $class['new']['ord_added_usr']; ?></textarea>
```

and it show me the date format like this

```
[120] Added by [admin] on [2016-05-18]
```

and I want to change the format into **Y-m-d** to **d-m-Y**

```
[120] Added by [admin] on [18-05-2016]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$class['new']['ord_added_usr']` holds `[120] Added by [admin] on [2016-05-18]`

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/", function($matches){
    return date("d-m-Y",strtotime($matches[0]));
},$class['new']['ord_added_usr']);
```

Result:

```
[120] Added by [admin] on [18-05-2016]
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/573107)

Answer (score 0):

extract the date from string and replace it with new format forming by

date function,

```
    $ori_str = $class['new']['ord_added_usr'];

    $extracted_date = substr($ori_str, strripos($ori_str,'[')+1 , 10);

    $new_date_format = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($extracted_date));


    $new_str = substr($ori_str, 0, strripos($ori_str,'[')+1).$new_date_format.']';
```

Comment: How to extract it?  var ctime = createdtime.match(/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)(.*)$/); how to put regex in php?

Answer (score 0):

First extract the date with `regex` , something like this: [regex to get date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564063/regex-to-get-date-yyyy-mm-dd-from-any-string)

Then format your date with `date` function, for reference: [date()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php)

Or use this function:

```
function formatDate($date, $divider = "-") {
    //Format date from MYSQL YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM to DD-MM-YYYY
    $hour= substr($date, strpos($date, " "));
    $year= substr($date, 0, 4);
    $month= substr($date, 5, 2);
    $day= substr($date, 8, 2);

    return $day. $divider . $month. $divider . $year;
}
```